# What is Thread.current for in the DCI in Ruby example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dci

What is `Thread.current` for in this code? I'm looking at [this](https://github.com/vsavkin/DCI-Sample) example of using DCI in a Rails application. In lib/context.rb, there's this:

```
module Context
  include ContextAccessor

  def context=(ctx)
    Thread.current[:context] = ctx
  end

  def in_context
    old_context = self.context
    self.context = self
    res = yield
    self.context = old_context
    res
  end
end
```

which is used in the various contexts in app/contexts, e.g.:

```
def bid
  in_context do
    validator.validate
    biddable.create_bid
  end
  #...
end
```

What is the benefit of running the code in the `in_context` block and setting a key-value pair on the current thread?

Comment: It's basically a global variable. Only thread-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, inside block you do not have an access to the caller’s context (besides closure variables.)

```
▶ class A
▷   attr_accessor :a
▷   def test
▷     yield if block_given?
▷   end  
▷ end  
#⇒ :test
▶ inst = A.new
#⇒ #<A:0x00000006f41e28>
▶ inst.a = 'Test'
#⇒ "Test"
▶ inst.test do 
▷   puts self
▷   # here you do not have an access to inst at all
▷   # this would raise an exception: puts self.a
▷ end
#⇒ main
```

But with context you still might have an access to `inst` from inside block:

```
▶ in_context do 
▷   puts self.context.a
▷ end
#⇒ 'Test'
```

So, one might introduce the `proc` (consider both `A` and `B` have `Context` included):

```
▶ pr = ->() { puts self.context }
▶ A.new.in_context &pr
#⇒ #<A:0x00000006f41e28>
▶ B.new.in_context &pr
#⇒ #<B:0x00000006f41eff>
```

Now external `proc` *`pr`* has virtually full access to *its caller*.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.current` is required to support multiple threading application, where each thread has its own context.

There is also [`ContextAccessor` module](https://github.com/vsavkin/DCI-Sample/blob/master/lib/context_accessor.rb) included, where one gets context. Putting them together just gives more clear picture:

```
# context.rb
def context=(ctx)
  Thread.current[:context] = ctx
end

# context_accessor.rb
def context
  Thread.current[:context]
end
```

The `in_context` method is designed to safely change context inside its block. Whatever the changes were, the old context is restored when the block ends execution.